# Why doesn't the road follow the curve?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, transforms

Ok so I was trying to find how to fix this problem. I found some answers but it did not work. So the problem is that I have a piece of road and I am trying to **align it with curve** so it could have beautiful L turn. But every time I tried to do it using array and curve modifiers it was always in same position and messed up transformation. Other roads (array) were next to each other - did not follow the curve. I tried moving road to curve center using cursor and same thing happend. The reason why I need this is so the road lines could line up perfectly. Any ideas how to fix it?

This question is similar to "Why is the curve modifier deforming strangely?"

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! It's hard to tell why this happens without seeing it. Could you please edit your question and upload some screenshots (maybe of the 3D View and the modifiers) or the .blend (blend-files go to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: Where @palkonimo wrote in his comment " ... *or* the .blend ... ", I would prefer, instead, "... *and* the blend".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image] If i understood your question. This is the answer 
Add a plane -- Add texture by uv mapping
Add a array modifier & curve modifier
In array Fit curve
And in Curve modifier -- object -- bezier curve
Click the bezier curve now and go to edit mode
and extrude and u will get the road with the path[image]

Comment: Yeah this is what I wanned.

Comment: Its confusing for me. I think I did same thing but this time it works. Thanks.