# Cannot make plane follow bezier or path

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

This is an really basic question, but I have been trying to solve it for for 45 minutes. Here is the blend file with the setup.
[image]

I've tried this [Why doesn't the road follow the curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69057/why-doesnt-the-road-follow-the-curve)
but it did not work.
The curve modifier, and above the array moddifier, with all the correct parameters, did not work.
Three possible scenarios:

- The plane just disappeared
- It go scaled massively
- Even with applying the transforms, it still did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what are you trying to do exactly? First you need to make some corrections: In *Edit* mode delete the vertex that is far away from your main plane, to do it select the plane with the lasso, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> to inverse the selection and catch the lone vertex, then <kbd>X</kbd> to delete. Also in *Object* mode apply the scale of the plane and curve. Now as the plane is a bit shorter than the curve, if you ask a *Fit Type* > *Fit Curve* it will duplicate once. You can choose the curve in the Curve modifier. If the plane scales crazy, it's because the curve's vertex radius are very high, so in *Edit* mode select them and in the 3D View *N* panel bring them down to 1. And if you want the plane to begin at the beginning of the curve, put the origin of the curve at this point.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll try that!